# How to configure auto completion?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm

Context:
I am trying to move from PyCharm to VSCode + Python extension.

The autocompletion on VSCode does not as well as on PyCharm.
As I am new with VSCode, I am not sure if it is a configuration issue on my side, or a bug on VSCode Python extension side.

E.g., when using selenium, with the following code snippet:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
elem = browser.find_element_by_id('toto')
elem.
```

PyCharm is able to give me the following suggestions:

[image: PyCharm screenshot]

But VSCode does not suggest anything:

[image: VSCode screenshot]

Can you guys reproduce the issue on your side?
Is this something I can fix on my side? how?
If not, then I'll file an issue.

Comment: Also:
If I mouse over 'find_element_by_id', I get details about the method.
But if I get to the code (via Ctrl + Click), then mouse over anything, I get 'Code analysis is in progress'.
So the issue may come from here. But how to investigate it?
https://imgur.com/gallery/XD0sSPe

Comment: VSCode is a code editor while Pycharm is an IDE, and a specialized one, so it might be normal. To have more information you can file an issue.

Comment: An issue is open on VSCode side: https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/785